# Multiple days of week in one attribute in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logic, days

I want to implement a feature in Rails using the option of multiple checkbox. User must be able to choose the days in which he want the emails, like Monday, Tuesday, etc. This must be a list of checkboxes with day name as label and day index like 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, like that.

Also these fields must be checked when the user next time come here to edit.
I don't want to create separate db field for each day. This can be an array of day index stored in one database field. I am using Rails version 4.

`Date::DAYNAMES` will give the list of week days. `Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index` will give the list of days with its index. I want to know the best way to implement the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
<%=select_tag 'days[]', options_for_select(Date::DAYNAMES.zip((0..6).to_a), 
[selected days array goes here]
), :multiple => true%>
```

### For using checkbox

```
<ul>
  <% Date::DAYNAMES.zip((0..6).to_a).each do |day| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag 'days[]', day[1], [selected days array].include?(day[1]) -%>
        <%= h day[0] -%>
      </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Hope it's help you.